# How to turn on sound captions in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I play on Minecraft Bedrock Edition, and for my own convenience, I wanted to turn on sound captions so I could play on low volume while not missing any important information. I looked it up, and it said that the option to turn it on should be in either "Music and Sounds" or "Accessibility", but I couldn't seem to find it in either.

Are sound captions simply non-existent in this edition, or is there some way I can turn them on? I know for a fact that it is in Java, but I can't seem to find any info on if it is in Bedrock. I'd like to note that I want to be able to turn them on completely vanilla, no mods or clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound captions do not exist in Minecraft: Bedrock Edition.

It seems like this has [already been requested on MC Feedback](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/community/posts/360075552892) as a parity request. Please vote for that idea instead of creating a new one, because duplicate ideas on MC Feedback are highly frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

I do know that there is an internal test regarding at least visual indicators. However, it is strongly noted that this will most likely NOT make it into future versions of the game. But rest assured, the peoples' voices have at least been heard. Screenshot attached!

[Minecraft 1.7.10 Accessibility Flight running on Xbox Series S](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWXfj.jpg)